# How to return to last activity after recents screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recents

I have an App with a main activity and a popup activity, if I stay in the app there is no problem. But if the popup activity is open and you re-enter the app from the recents screen only the popup activity is shown. If you then close it you don't return to the main activity but the app closes completely.

This opens the popup activity from the main activity:

```
intent = new Intent(ctx, popupActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("rackName", resultChest.get(2));

ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

And here is the method which closes the popup activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    finish();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lchr"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_lchr"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_lchr_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".popupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/popupTheme"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Solution**:
as @RedWolf mentioned `android:launchMode = "singleInstance"` causes the activity to open in another task which causes my problem.
To resolve this and prevent the popup activity to open twice I had to use `android:launchMode = "singleTop"` for the popup activity.

Comment: Show `AndroidManifest.xml` file as well.

Comment: @VicJordan sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `android:launchMode = "singleInstance"`, it will create a new task.

Comment: oh great to know, using    android:launchMode = "standard", solves my problem. But the reason i was using singleInstance was to prevent the prevent the popupActivity from opening twice. And with android:launchMode = "standard" it again openes twice.

Comment: Did you try android:launchMode = "singleTop" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

Go to popupActivity.java then
Override the method named OnBackPressed
And add finish(); to it

Code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      finish();
  }
```

Comment: Tho I would be better able to answer the question if you could upload the screenshot of the problem.

Comment: if you press back the popup activity closes but not if you acces the recents screen, and the problem stays the same.

Comment: This should work to make sure finish leads to previous activity

Add parent activity in manifest like this

<activity android:name=".popupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/popupTheme"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance">